# gridstack.js set grid-stack-item height auto based on inner content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, grid, gridstack

Is there any option to use `gridstack.js` with each `grid-stack-item` `height` based on inner content like `image`.

In my scenario each `images` having different height so it's not showing correctly on card.

It gives scrollbar inside `grid-stack-item` to view image, that is wrong.

Any option or workaround or other JS plugin/library that will restrict fixed height based on any factor.

**Current behavior**

[image: Current behavior]

**Expected behavior**

Height will be `100%` based on width so image `aspect ratio` preserves.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do by setting up `cellHeight` : `10` then get `image` in `resizestop` event and update `updateWidget`.

Below is sample code for that `resizestop` event.

```
 $('.grid-stack').on('resizestop', function (e, item) {
        let stackItem = me.findGridStackItem(item.element.find('img').data('Id'));
        if (stackItem) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                stackItem.option.height = Math.ceil(($(stackItem.nativeElement).find('img').height() + 5) / 10);                   
                me.gridStackMain.updateWidget(stackItem);                
            }, 200);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem you are facing is about creating "masonry layout". I think gridstack is not the tool you need to use to resolve this problem. Try https://masonry.desandro.com/ or any other masonry layout lib.